# Example of a function that is easy to invert "in layers"

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Define $g(x) = f_n(f_{n-1}(...f_1(x)))$ where each $f_i$, $i=1, ...,n$ is an invertible function.  Then do there exist a class of functions $f_i$ such that $g$ defined by composing the $f_i$ is "difficult" to invert when given just $g$, but becomes easy to invert when done by inverting each $f_i$ in reverse order?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an answer based on intuition, I feel justified to write it because it has not been given a formal definition of what it is meant with "difficult to invert".

We know that there is not a a general formula to solve by radicals every polynomial function of degree at least $5$ (Abel–Ruffini theorem),Then let's consider $n=1$ and as $f_1$ a polynomial function of degree at least $5$ of such kind.

Then you have $g=f_1$ that is "quite easy to write down" but "hard" to invert.

So the class of functions that are "hard" to invert must contain a sizeable subset of the polynomials functions of degree at least 5... So it has to be a very big class...